# Django form.is_valid() not validating

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I can't seem to get my form to validate with .is_valid()

## The associated View

```
def edit_social_media(request, user_id):

#verify a user is allowed to access the page

# user is saving the form
if request.POST:

form = SocialMediaForm(request.POST)
if form.is_valid():
 ...

  return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse(users.profile,
                                   args = (request.user.id,)))

# displaying the initial form
else:
   try:
     form = SocialMediaForm(instance = SocialMedia.objects.get(user = request.user))
   except SocialMedia.DoesNotExist:
     form = SocialMediaForm()


return render_to_response('users/edit_social_media.html', {'form': form, 'user' : user},
 context_instance = RequestContext(request))
```

## Forms.py

```
class SocialMediaForm(forms.ModelForm):
   class Meta:
      model = SocialMedia
      fields = {'twitter', 'facebook', 'linkedin'}
```

## the template

```
<form method="post" action=''>
{% csrf_token %}
<div class="form-col-left">
    <p>
    {{ form.as_p }}
</p>
</div>


<div class="submitbutton">
<input type="submit" class="green button" value="Save Social Media Settings" />
</div>

</form>
```

## The model

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class SocialMedia(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        app_label = 'dashboard'

  #the user associated with the data
  user = models.ForeignKey(User)

  #Twitter, Facebook, and Linkedin pages
  twitter = models.URLField("Twitter")
  facebook = models.URLField("Facebook")
  linkedin = models.URLField("Linkedin")
```

Some help would be greatly appreciated. I'm rather new to django so I've been missing some of the smaller nuances. I've found some similar issues on stackoverflow related to bound vs unbound forms, but from reading the documentation I think I properly bound the data to the form.

Answer (score 1):

Since this is a ModelForm it would help seeing the actual Model that this form is using, the SocialMedia class.  Also I am not sure what you mean by not getting it to validate but I am assuming that the is_valid() method returns False.

My guess is that the method returns False because you are not setting the user on the form.  In the POST dictionary you don't have the user or user_id.  Add the following line before the "if form.is_valid()" statement:

form.instance.user = self.request.user

Hope this works.

Comment: I've edited to add the associated model.py. form.instance.user = self.request.user didn't seem to fix the problem.

Comment: are you sure you are filling in all fields?  if so, what error do you get on the page?

Comment: the form fields? I'm fairly certain i'm filling them all in. Though the model has a user field as well, but I believe we already addressed that. 
i don't get an error. I have an if statement set up such that if form.is_valid() render one page, else render a different page.
What information could i provide to be more helpful?